# "can I trace Specific module? Using Frida "

Tags: android, android-webview, frida

I analyzed a android apk, i want to know about some principle

the apk have only one function that access Internet

then apk code is simple

just use - webview.loadUrl

in that time i want to know

"webview.loadurl"

I want to know which module this function call(loadurl)

If you know, please let me know the keyword or url.

in the Frida API
"enumberateMoudle / enumberateClass" is just enumberating loaded Module and Class, so it's not what i want

and call stack trace just below :(This is not the area I want.)

```
android.webkit.WebView.loadUrl(Native Method)
com.example.user.webview2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6999)
android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6990)
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)'}
```

Comment: Do you want to know which url the application loads or what goes on when webview.loadUrl is called?

Comment: i want to know Specific module, 
I want to know which "*.so module" are used when connecting to the Internet.

Comment: Your question is confusing me. You are taking about "one function that access Internet" in the app, and you show the WebView code called from the MainActivity. However later you are talking about native libraries (*.so files), and when they access the Internet. WebView and native libraries usually have nothing to to with each other. Therefore you are just trying to hook the native socket functions like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43635415) right?

Comment: Webview typically operates out of libwebviewchromium.so - a compiled version of Chrome for Android. The network calls then go through the usual libc.so module via the send/sendto native socket functions. Were you trying to hook there?

Comment: Thanks to Robert , Nebel22
I am sorry that my question is dizzy. 
Once I'm talking to the Android network. In the Webview, loadUrl() Function is to Acess a Specific URL. So when I tried to access the internet through this function, I noticed that the Connect() function of libc.so was used. So how does libc.so be used by loadurl's function?

Comment: The answer of your last comment has already been answered in Nebel22s comment before yours.

Comment: You might be able to achieve what you want in Frida-Trace, as well:  https://github.com/frida/frida/issues/249

Answer (score 0):

```
frida-trace --help

-I MODULE, --include-module=MODULE
-X MODULE, --exclude-module=MODULE
```

I like to trace items by spawning the app, on my device ( over USB ) like this..

```
frida-trace -I YDApiKit -U -f com.youd.mobile
```

You can do the same with [Frida-Interceptor](https://www.frida.re/docs/javascript-api/#interceptor).